# Concerning the existence of a divergent monotone sequence with a Cauchy subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Is my argument correct?

> **Proposition.** There is no divergent monotone sequence with a Cauchy subsequence.

*Proof.* Assume that we have a divergent monotone sequence $(a_n)$ with a Cauchy sequence $(a_{n_k})$, from theorem $\textbf{2.6.3}$ we know that there exists an $M>0$ such that $|a_{n_k}|<M,\forall k\in\mathbf{N}$.

We now examine the case where $(a_n)$ is increasing, the case where $(a_n)$ is decreasing will be handled similarly. Let $r\in\mathbf{N}$, evidently $r\leq n_r$ but then $a_r\leq a_{n_r}$ and since $a_{n_r}\leq |a_{n_r}|\leq M$ consequently $a_r\leq M$, implying that $(a_n)$ is bounded, but $(a_n)$ cannot be bounded since this together with $(a_n)$ being increasing would imply $(a_n)$ is convergent by theorem $\textbf{2.4.1}$.

$\blacksquare$

**Note:**

- $\textbf{2.6.3}$ All Cauchy sequences are bounded.
- $\textbf{2.4.1}$ All bounded monotone sequeces are convergent.

Comment: Correct! Good job. And yes, you showed that there is no such thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that was indeed my intention what would you say is wrong?

Comment: The statement. Say "there is no"...

Comment: @A.Pongrácz Thanks corrections made